# Applescript claims to run shell script, but script has no effect

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line, bash, script

So I have a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE='some_file.js'
gsed -i -E 's/something/somethingelse/' "$FILE"
echo "Modified File"
```

When I run this from command line, it echoes the last line, so no errors or something and makes changes to the file. I then try to create an Applescript with these contents:

```
set msg to do shell script "/path/to/script.sh"
display dialog msg
```

When I run it, it dutifully displays the dialog, but does not actually change the file `some_file.js`.
How can this be possible?

**Update**: If I use `sed -i "" -E 's/something/somethingelse/' "$FILE"` instead, it works.

Comment: Where is gsed? Reading more I'll bet not on the path. Altering ~/.bash( files will not chnage this - I would use the full path to gsed

Comment: @Mark Oh it's in the `PATH` alright. It's installed via macports. But setting the full path does help. I thought I would be alerted with an error message (as I have seen before) that the command was not found, but apparently the applescript just silently fails.

Comment: Do you capture stderr? How did yeast the PATH?

Comment: PATH als seen in Terminal may not be the same as PATH in Automator, so it's best to add the full path to non-standard commands.